# Ldaptemplate search returns same entry the correct number of times

Tags: java, ldap

I have been working on trying to search for all users within the LDAP directory.  When I perform the search, it comes back as the correct number of entries I have in the directory, but it is all duplicates of the same entry (the last one).  I cannot seem to figure out why this is.  Here are some of my code snippets:

Function that actually performs the search:

```
public List<User> getAllUsers(){
    AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
    filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "person"));
    List<User> users = ldapTemplate.search(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH,
                            filter.encode(), new UserAttributesMapper());

    return users;
}
```

User is just a class with getters and settings that contains all the information about the user.  The `UserAttributesMapper` is as follows:

```
private static class UserAttributesMapper implements AttributesMapper {
    public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) throws NamingException {
        ...
        User user = (User) AppUtils.getBean("user");    
        NamingEnumeration ae = attrs.getAll();
        ...
        //set user attributes through setters
        // ie: if(attrs.get("uid") != null) user.setUid((String) attrs.get("uid").get());
        ...
        return user;
    }
}
```

I know the mapper works because I can return one user with no problems and it works beautifully.  I just don't understand why it is returning the `List` full of only the last user entry.  One of my thoughts was the use of `static` in the statement

```
User user = (User) AppUtils.getBean("user");
```

The User class is annotated with `@Component("user")` and the function for `getBean` is

```
public static Object getBean(final String name) {
    if(applicationContext == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "ApplicationContext is not initialized");
    }
    return applicationContext.getBean(name);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you are using the same User object in every position of the list, so you keep updating the same one, instead of creating a new one per search result.

Comment: I have no idea how I overlooked something so simple, but thanks!